# Call php file to return an array, and load it into a combo box

Tags: php, html

I have my index.php. I want to call a function in load_data.php which would return an array. I then want to load that array into a combox box on index.php. Can anyone help me get started on this? I'm brand new to php and trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Do yo need to call via AJAX or inside your PHP script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

load_data.php

```
function get_data() {
    // May be you want to load data from DB
    // This is just a hint
    return array('key1' => 'Value 1', 'key2' => 'Value 2');
}
```

And in your main file:

```
<select name="myselect">
    <?php
    include 'load_data.php';
    $data = get_data();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: You can accept answer if you are thinking this is the most suitable answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without reloading the page, you'll need to look into AJAX. If you want to do this at the time you request the page, you can [include the page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and call any functions out of it.